# Make img occupy always 800*400 px space even it is smaller in size(without scaling up)

Tags: html, css

I am using Jquery Lazy Load plugin to load images lazily when they come in the viewport of browser.

In place of the original image, I just place an animated loader gif. However because there is a difference in the dimensions of the animated loader gif & original image I see the original image shrinked in size.

I want to make the loader gif hold the entire space that would have been used by original image to be placed. (loader gif is 32*32 px & original img is 800*400px)
So I want that the image rendered by the code below should always occupy 800*400px space without the loader image scaling up to that size. I think that is possible through CSS, but I dont know how? Could you please guide me on this ?

```
<img class='lazy' data-original='/module_files/l.jpg' src='/loader.gif'/>
```

Comment: just use a css background with your loader image. So `<img style="background:url(loading.gif) no-repeat" ...`. To give the image the right dimension while the image is not yet loaded you need to specify the widht and height attributes. So `<img width="800" height="400" ...`

Comment: @Gerben - hmm, I like this idea and it didn't occur to me. You should post it as an actual answer! By setting src to '' the bg image will show.

Comment: @Gerben - I couldn't figure out how to remove the src attribute once it was set. Which broke your solution in the end. Would love to see this though! http://jsfiddle.net/uNbMN/5/

Comment: you should just set the image to some spacer gif or something. Setting it to `src=""` will make some browsers think it is a relative urls, and load the current page-url as an image which will not return any data that the browser can show (since it's html, not e.g. jpg), which will result in the browser not showing an 'empty' image.

Comment: @Gerben - Ahh, thanks for letting me know why `src=""` did not work. Unfortunately because he has dimensions set on actual image, even setting it to spacer causes the spacer to stretch out and fill area. I guess exactly what he wants is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/uNbMN/1/

There are a lot of ways to solve this, but just using a single `img` tag and no js I don't think there is a very good way. You can't tell an img to center inside itself, because you are setting the actual dimensions. You could do something like this with two classes.

```
img.lazy {
    height: 400px;
    width: 800px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

img.loader {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    /*You would have to account for loader dimensions here*/
    padding: 200px 400px 200px 400px;
}
```

If you really want to do this I would consider separating 'loader' from the image completely and placing it in its own, separate element.